# Prevent child div from inheriting parent width

Tags: html, css

I have a child div with a border that should only wrap as much as the text. However, it seems to inherit the parent div's width.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xstaf3cc/

```
<div class="contentContainer">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Posted by u/user1</div>
  <div class="text">
    Text
  </div>
</div>

.contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15;
}

.text {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

How can I make the width of 'Text' not inherit its parent div's width? I would like its width to just be as long as the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `align-items: flex-start;` style on `contentContainer` div

```css
 
.contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
<div>
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Posted by u/user1</div>
</div>  
<span class="text">
  Text
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**use**     `width: fit-content;` to `.text`

```css
.contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid black;
      width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div>
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Posted by u/user1</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```